# How do I resolve an "IndentationError"?

Tags: python, image, bots, discord, discord.py

I am making a Discord bot and trying to have it send images.

These are all my imports:

```
 import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
import asyncio
import random
import time
import ftplib
```

Then I have this code:

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="2")
```

Then I have this one that when I launch my run.py it shows me some prints in the app:

```
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("I'm running on: " + bot.user.name)
    print ("With the ID: " + (bot.user.id))
    print("The commands are \n" + "#ping \n #pong \n #info (@user) \n #embedtest \n #hello \n #hug \n #kill \n ")
```

This is my code for the picture, so this code should make a picture pop up from the same folder as my run.py program is located.

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def image(ctx):
myImage = open('UDST.png', 'rb') 
await bot.send_file(myImage)
```

But then when I run it, it gives me this error that I don't understand.

> ```
> C:\Users\david>"C:\Users\david\Desktop\UDST Bot\Udst bot.py"
>   File "C:\Users\david\Desktop\UDST Bot\Udst bot.py", line 105
>     await bot.send_file(myImage)
>                                ^
> IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
> ```

How do I resolve this error?

Comment: Did you have a look at similar threads in SO? See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492387/indentationerror-unindent-does-not-match-any-outer-indentation-level) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26720878/8881141)

Comment: Why is there no indentation?

Answer (score 0):

To echo what wright commented the problem is likely due to the fact you haven't indented after your function (you're getting an indentation error).

this

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def image(ctx):
myImage = open('UDST.png', 'rb') 
await bot.send_file(myImage)
```

should be this

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def image(ctx):
    myImage = open('UDST.png', 'rb') 
    await bot.send_file(myImage)
```

If that doesn't work you can try out some of the examples of sending an image as found on the [discord.py docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#how-do-i-upload-an-image).  One of the examples shows that you can send an image just by passing the file name,

```
await client.send_file(channel, 'your_image_file_here.png')
```

Hope that solves your problem!